# Quarkus with hibernate found [bpchar (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [char (Types#VARCHAR)]

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

Hello i'm trying to learn Quarkus with Hibernate but i've ran into an issue the schema-validation.

The error:

> 2021-12-29 16:05:14,915 ERROR
> [io.qua.hib.orm.run.sch.SchemaManagementIntegrator] (Hibernate
> post-boot validation thread for ) Failed to validate Schema:
> Schema-validation: wrong column type encount ered in column [BED_INFO]
> in table [ROOM]; found [bpchar (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [char
> (Types#VARCHAR)] 2021-12-29 16:05:14,921 ERROR
> [io.qua.hib.orm.run.sch.SchemaManagementIntegrator] (Hibernate
> post-boot validation thread for ) The following SQL may
> resolve the database issues, as generated by the Hibernate schema
> migration tool. WARNING: You must manually verify this SQL is correct,
> this is a best effort guess, do not copy/paste it without verifying
> that it does what you expect.

the class Room looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROOM")
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ROOM_NUMBER")
    private String roomNumber;
    @Column(name = "BED_INFO", columnDefinition = "char")
    private String bedInfo;

    public Room(String name, String roomNumber, String bedInfo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.bedInfo = bedInfo;
    }

}
```

and the mysql schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE ROOM(
  ROOM_ID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  ROOM_NUMBER CHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  BED_INFO CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
```

According to their documentation this "should" work but i'm  perhaps missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[BED_INFO] in table [ROOM]; found [bpchar (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [char (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

Means that Hibernate has found a bpchar(char) where it would expect a varchar. It seems that `columnDefinition` does not handle `char`. If you really want it to be a `char`, try `bpchar` instead.

In case it doesn't work, try running your quarkus app in dev mode with this option in the application.properties file.

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=create
```

This will generate the actual DDL for your database that Hibernate is expecting.

Personally I would refrain from `columnDefinition`, instead i would use `length` and `nullable`. Unless you are building an app on an existent, I would also remove `name` and `@Table`.